# How to show the legend in HighCharts

Tags: jquery, legend, highcharts

I am working with [Hightcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), I try to show the legend of the chart, but I have no idea why don't show it.

```
  function multipleCharts(current_data) {
  var seriesOptions = [],
    type = ['jobs_running', 'jobs_pending'];
  for (var j = 0; j < current_data.length; j++) {
    var project = current_data[j]['name'];
    for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
      seriesOptions.push({
        name: project + ' ' + type[i],
        data: current_data[j][type[i]]
      });
    }
  }
  $('#containerChart').highcharts('StockChart', {

    tooltip: {
      formatter: function(){
        s = '';
        $.each(this.points, function(){
          s += '<br/>' + '<span style="color:'+ this.series.color +'; text-transform: uppercase;">' + this.series.name + ':' + '</span>'+ ' ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0) + ' jobs';
        });
        return s;
      },
    },
    legend: {
      labelFormatter: function() {
        serie_name = '';
        $.each(this.series, function(){
          serie_name +=  this.series.name + '<br/>';
        });
        return serie_name;
      },
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: 'none',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            r: 8,
            style: {
                color: '#f47321',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                },
                select: {
                    fill: '#f47321',
                    style: {
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }
                // disabled: { ... }
            }
        },
        inputBoxBorderColor: '#005030',
        inputBoxWidth: 120,
        inputBoxHeight: 18,
        inputStyle: {
            color: '#005030',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        labelStyle: {
            color: '#005030',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        selected: 0
    },
    series: seriesOptions
  });
}
```

even I try something like this, very easy, and didn't show anything

```
legend: {
    title: {
        text: 'hola',
        style: {
            fontStyle: 'italic'
        }
    },

},
```

Any idea!
Thanks in advances

Comment: Can you provide any similar fiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In legend set enabled to true.

```
legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Mulaye, I don't know why don't show me anything before if  the doc say "Enable or disable the legend. Defaults to true"

Comment: Thanks! Btw, how come the examples in the doc don't need this field? For example: [Legend at the right of the chart](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/align/)